# While loop along with other function

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to set up a little game similar to craps but much simpler. Here's my code:

```
first.roll <- sum(ceiling(6*runif(2)))

playCraps <- function(x){ 
  if (x == 7 | x == 11)
  print("Win!")
  else if (x == 2 | x == 3 | x == 12)
  print("Lose!")
  else
  rollAgain(x)
}

rollAgain <- function(y) {
  while (y != first.roll & y != 7) {
    y <- sum(ceiling(6*runif(2)))
  }
  return(y)
}

playCraps(first.roll)
```

I've set it up like this, but I have the feeling something's missing.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand how to set up a while loop in relation to another function. How can I set up a while loop that will keep iterating a function until it reaches two results? Do I combine the while loop with if statements?

Comment: Check your `while` logic. If `first.roll` is any number other than 7, then your condition will always be true. If `first.roll` is 5, then `(y != 5 |(or) y !=7 )` will be true always. It can't be equal to both numbers. But generally we're not here to debug for you. You should try to ask a specific programming question.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you! I didn't mean to ask for debugging, I just wanted to make sure there was enough context